# Extremely slow MongoCursor::next() performance

Tags: php, performance, mongodb

I was faced with an extremely slow `MongoCursor` performance under some conditions.

```php
$mongoClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
$collection = $mc->mydb->mycollection;
```

#### test1:

```php
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++)
{
    $cursor = $collection->find()->limit(2);
    $cursor->next();
}
```

*Elapsed time: 41.78210 sec [**24 ops/s**]*

#### test2:

```php
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++)
{
    $cursor = $collection->find()->limit(1);
    $cursor->next();
}
```

*Elapsed time: 0.47898 sec [**2 088 ops/s**]*

#### test3:

```php
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++)
{
    $cursor = $collection->find()->limit(2)->batchSize(-2);
    $cursor->next();
}
```

*Elapsed time: 0.65439 sec [**1 528 op/s**]*

In **test1** no matter whether `limit(2)` or `limit(200)` script does 24 ops/s always;

I tested it with:

- mongo v2.4.5
- php driver 1.4.0dev and 1.5.0dev
- Debian 6.0.7 and Ubuntu 12.10

Is this some issue in php driver?

### EDIT1:

I did some logging via MongoLog and got interesting results:

```
MongoLog::setLevel(MongoLog::ALL);
MongoLog::setModule(MongoLog::IO);
```

**test1:** (limit(N) where N > 1)

- 1375693731.5349 - IO (FINE): getting reply
- 1375693731.5350 - IO (FINE): getting cursor header
- 1375693731.5351 - IO (FINE): getting cursor body
- 1375693731.5351 - IO (WARN): Killing unfinished cursor 63182808988603511
- 1375693731.5352 - IO (FINE): getting reply
- **1375693731.5353 - IO (FINE): getting cursor header**
- **1375693731.5726 - IO (FINE): getting cursor body**
- 1375693731.5727 - IO (WARN): Killing unfinished cursor 63182981334616260
- ...

**test2:** (limit(1), limit(0) and without limit )

- 1375693866.2663 - IO (FINE): getting reply
- 1375693866.2663 - IO (FINE): getting cursor header
- 1375693866.2663 - IO (FINE): getting cursor body
- 1375693866.2665 - IO (FINE): getting reply
- 1375693866.2665 - IO (FINE): getting cursor header
- 1375693866.2665 - IO (FINE): getting cursor body
- ...

as you can see when I limit query with N (where N>1) driver does `killing unfinished cursor` and next time when it tries to get cursor body it spends to much time.

### EDIT2:

Yes, that timings concern collection with 20 documents only, but 20K documents will affect only limit(0) and noLimit, they will do kill cursor as you said.

Here is the log with logLevel:5. I don't any clues.

**mongodb.log:** limit(N)

- Mon Aug  5 14:43:55.292 [conn3] query mydb.mycollection cursorid:1002459676459826 ntoreturn:2 ntoskip:0 nscanned:3 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:84 nreturned:2 reslen:86 0ms
- Mon Aug  5 14:43:55.293 [conn3] killcursors: found 1 of 1
- Mon Aug  5 14:43:55.**293** [conn3] killcursors  keyUpdates:0  0ms
- Mon Aug  5 14:43:55.**332** [conn3] runQuery called mydb.mycollection {}
- Mon Aug  5 14:43:55.333 [conn3] query mydb.mycollection cursorid:1002631131988423  ntoreturn:2 ntoskip:0 nscanned:3 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:84 nreturned:2 reslen:86 0ms

**mongodb.log:** limit(1)

- Mon Aug  5 14:45:54.899 [conn3] runQuery called mydb.mycollection {}
- Mon Aug  5 14:45:54.899 [conn3] query mydb.mycollection ntoreturn:1 ntoskip:0 nscanned:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:39 nreturned:1 reslen:53 0ms
- Mon Aug  5 14:45:54.899 [conn3] runQuery called mydb.mycollection {}
- Mon Aug  5 14:45:54.899 [conn3] query mydb.mycollection ntoreturn:1 ntoskip:0 nscanned:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:35 nreturned:1 reslen:53 0ms

Comment: Tried your code with driver v1.3.7, had no performance drop. Try this version.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are running this, and how many items you have on my collection, but all of the three tests take 0.102-0.112 seconds—no matter how many items I have either. Far faster than what you run. This is with PHP 5.4 and driver version 1.5.0dev.

The "Killing unfinished cursor" message is because you are not reading all of the found data that belongs to the result set indicated by the cursor. I presume you tested that with only having 20 items in your collection, and not 20k, as that would *also* show the message.

By default, the first batch that is being read from MongoDB is 101 documents. So if your result set is less than that, then there **is** no cursor.

`limit(1)` and `limit(n)` where `n < 0` are special as they mean "give me `abs(n)` many results and then close the cursor".

`limit(0)` and no limit given just mean "give me the default batch"—which for the initial result is 101 documents. I've written extensively about this at http://drck.me/mongocur-9f8

Now as to where you get the 37ms slow down for after a killed cursor is still a mystery. Perhaps you can have a look whether your `mongodb.log` file has any insights? (I'll update the answer again if I see that info)

Comment: `mycollection` has only 20 items (it's doesn't matter, i tried on collections with 20K documents and more). I tried dbs on different servers and couldn't get rid of this performance drop.